# ajax-created links not working like hard-coded links (css object class actions)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I found a cool modal css package that allows you to pop up windows with css (i'd share the link, but idk if that's 'allowed'..). I export what they offered and uploaded it to my site and it works perfectly. All the different buttons open and close modals as expected. So i started to expand it and tried to introduce a simple javascript function on a (classic) asp page that makes an ajax call to a different asp page that returns a string, which also works as expected. Then i wanted to have a link that was created in the ajax response that would also work as the elements that are hard-coded on the page do, which is where the problem came from. The ajax response has the same code as a button/link on the actual page, but when they're clicked nothing happens.

Here's the javascript in my index.asp page:

`function ajaxCall(qStr) {`

```
if (qStr.length==0) {
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = "";
    return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getHint.asp?which=2&q=" + qStr,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

This is the form on the page that calls the ajaxCall function:

`<form>Client's Name: <input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxCall(this.value)" size="20">
</form>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>`

the other page (getHint.asp) runs a loop in the db to find all items which match the entered string in the form, which works. here is the bit that is most important from that page:

`leResult = leResult & "<a href=""#"" onClick=""alert('ajax response link clicked.');"" class=""md-close md-trigger"" data-modal=""clientSearch"" style=""color: #ffffff;"">" & rs.fields("name") & "</a>, "`

so all the 'results' are concatenated and output at the end of the loop, which again works. and not to get too into the particulars of the css starting point, but any object with the class "md-close" will close the modal that it's in, but that part isnt working.

Is there something additional i have to do to have the page recognize the response from the ajax call and let it manipulate the page too?

I have taken the code on the getHint.asp page and pasted it to the index.asp page, and that link works as it should. I've used firebug and the response from the ajax call is coded identically to the link just a bit lower on the page, but the only one that works is the one that's hard-coded.

Oh, and i put the javascript alert in the response that says "ajax response link clicked," which does work when the link is clicked, but the modal stays open.

thanks for looking, any pointers are greatly appreciated.

update: as requested in the comments, this is the javascript that handles the clicking of objects with the md-close class:

`var ModalEffects = (function() {`

```
function init() {

    var overlay = document.querySelector( '.md-overlay' );

    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.md-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

        var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) ),
            close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' );

        function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
            classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

            if( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
            }
        }

        function removeModalHandler() {
            removeModal( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ); 
        }

        el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
            overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
            overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

            if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }, 25 );
            }
        });

        close.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            removeModalHandler();
        });

    } );

}

init();
```

})();

Comment: Are all those double `""` characters part of your server-side markup that get translated into single `"` characters?  If those make it to the client-side, you've got all sorts of issues.

Comment: Yes, the double quotes become a single quote when the page is translated. and to test that, i took the same part of the code (minus the "leResult = leResult &" part) and put it in a `<% response.write() %>` to mimic it exactly

Comment: Can you post your code to handle clicks on links with the `md-close` class?

Comment: i edited the original post to include that

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that at the point you are binding your listen events to all elements with the class `md-close`, the elements that are loaded from the JavaScript call don't exist yet. Subsequently, the events aren't bound to them, and when they are created after the AJAX call their click events aren't firing - because they aren't bound.

Basically - when you attach your events you only bind to all existing elements with class `md-close`, not every element with the same class that might exist in the future.

You'll need to re-run the code to attach the listen events to the new elements inside the `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` block, just after you add the AJAX loaded mark-up to the page. You'll have to be careful to not add listeners twice to existing mark-up too, but hopefully this answer gives you enough information to refactor your code to achieve what you're after.

If you want to switch to jQuery it will probably help overall, but if you don't have any experience with the library then you'll have to learn a lot as you go. The analogous situation to yours in jQuery is that a normal click handler for your class would be done like this (for simplicities sake, make a new .js file named whatever you like and link to it **after** you link to the jQuery library itself):

```
$(function() {
    $('.md-close').click(function() {
        console.log('close button clicked');
    });
});
```

This basically puts you where you were with your original question with your listener bound only to elements which exist when your page loads. The first anonymous function is jQuery shorthand for the document load event (http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and the second anonymous function adds the `click()` function to all elements in the document with class `.md-close`.

To re-write this in the way you need so that it works with elements created after load, your new .js file should look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#outputDiv").on('click', '.md-close', function() {
        console.log('close button clicked');
    });
});
```

This uses the same method of running on document load, but the event itself attaches to `#outputDiv` - an element which is in the page when it loads. It then fires a click event every time it or any of it's children are clicked, and your parameters say you only want your anonymous function to run when the clicked element has a class of `.md-close`. This works from the DOM as it exists when the event is fired, so will include newly added elements.

With just those five lines of code in a new .js file linked after the jQuery library you should see the appropriate console messages when you click your close button and you should have the starting point you need to solve your original problem. The jQuery documentation is of a high quality and contains plenty of examples: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: that makes complete sense, and i didnt know how to articulate that enough for a resourceful google search... and now that i tried, everything i find creates javascript functions that fire when the action happens, which according to them would be as simple as: $("#outputDiv").on('click','md-close', function () { -- but that's not doing anything for me.

Comment: That is jQuery code; you'll need to add the library to your page if you want to use it.

Comment: And you would want a full stop to indicate a class: '.md-close'

Comment: i do have the jquery library added, and i was missing that period, but once i added it, it still didnt do anything. do you know of any tutorials similar to this situation you could refer me to?

Comment: I'll add to my answer to try and get you on the right path with jQuery.